# Serde missing field error when deserializing json file

Tags: json, rust, serde

I can't seem to grasp why this error is happening.

Am I following the [docs](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) wrong?

This is the error I am getting and it happens with all the fields in the struct except the map:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("missing field `link`", line: 10, column: 1)', src\main.rs:22:47
```

This is my `main.rs`

```
use serde_json::{self, Value};
use std::{fs, collections::HashMap};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Init {
    link: String,
    page: String,
    pageid: u16,
    update_timestamp: u16,

    #[serde(flatten)]
    char_page_info: HashMap<String, Value>
}

fn main() {
    let data = fs::read_to_string("init.json").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("{}", data);
    let p: Init = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", p.char_page_info); 
}
```

This is the `init.json`

```
{
    "char_page_info": [
        {
            "link": "",
            "page": "GGST/Jack-O/Frame_Data",
            "pageid": 27121,
            "update_timestamp": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

If i remove `link: String,` `page: String,` `pageid: u16,` `update_timestamp: u16,`

it doesn't throw any errors and deserializes without any hiccups.

Can someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cf51273b45d92b392f51059c954f257)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just `link` that is missing: Serde bails at the first error. `link`, `page`, and `pageid`, and `update_timestamp` are all missing. Serde looks for those fields on the top level object, and doesn't find them, since the only key present there is `char_page_info`. Since there can be multiple values of `char_page_info` (it is an array), your `struct` doesn't model the underlying data correctly. By fully modelling the data, we can get the expected results:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Init {
    link: String,
    page: String,
    pageid: u16,
    update_timestamp: u16,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    char_page_info: Vec<Init>,
}

let data = r#"{
    "char_page_info": [
        {
            "link": "",
            "page": "GGST/Jack-O/Frame_Data",
            "pageid": 27121,
            "update_timestamp": 0
        }
    ]
}"#;
println!("{}", data);
let p: Data = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", p.char_page_info);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=028868871287604079e271d4fc787459)

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes perfect sense now. Thanks!