# Rust Error("missing field `key`") when deserializing to JSON

Tags: rust, serde-json, rocket

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408593/serde-missing-field-error-when-deserializing-json-file) solution but it didn't work.

I always get the error `Error("missing field key")` and want to know how to fix this.

Code:

```rust
pub fn get_user(id: String) -> Data  {
    let cache: RedisCache = RedisCache;

    let s: String = cache.get_str(&id).unwrap();
    println!("{}", &s);
    let user: Data = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();

    user
}
```

The `id = 40:a3:cc:a3:dc:43` returns:

```json
{"change":"new","data":[],"token":"2a256356"}
```

This output is correct but deserializing this `String` into `Data` gives me the error.

Data looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, ToSchema, Clone)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
pub struct Data {
    /// Device's MAC address.
    #[schema(example = "40:a3:cc:a3:dc:43")]
    pub key: String,
    /// Data from a device.
    #[schema(value_type = Object, 
        example = "{ token: 2a256356, change: new, data: [ { dns: www.google.de, mac: 40:a3:cc:a3:dc:43, src: 10.42.0.177, dst: 10.42.0.1} ] }",
    )]
    pub value: Vec<Value>,
    /// Indication whether task is done or not.
    pub done: bool,
}
```

I'm working with [utoipa](https://github.com/juhaku/utoipa) and `rocket 0.5`.

Comment: Can you please include the use statements needed for this?

Comment: In your `Data` structure, there's a `key` field which is missing in JSON you've shown. How should it be filled when deserializing?

Comment: It should be the function argument which you can see in my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating `Data` instead using `from_str()`:

```rust
pub fn get_user(id: String) -> Data  {
    let cache: RedisCache = RedisCache;

    let s: String = cache.get_str(&id).unwrap_or("Problem finding the user".to_string());
    println!("{}", &s);
    let user: Data = Data { key: id, value: vec![serde_json::json!(&s.as_str())], done: false };

    user
}
```